# Issue Getting Model object in MVC to jQuery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass my MVC Model object in the view to the Controller Action method To access to my DB.......... Where i'm going to add that element into the DB......... But i'm not sure how to get that model object into a jQuery variable........ I have tried two ways to do that.......

```
var modelDataJSON = @Model;
var modelDataJSON = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

These both ways gives me a syntax errors..........
this is how my jQuery function looks like:

```
$('#submit').click(function () {    
    var modelDataJSON = @Model;
    @*var modelDataJSON = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));*@    
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '@Url.Action("AddDoctor")',
          data: {"doctor" : modelDataJSON},
          success: function (data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data.Message));     
          },
          error: function () {
                alert("Error!!!");
         }

    });
    return false;  


});
```

this is how my form looks like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddDoctor", "Doctor"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4></h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })*@
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> User ID</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserId, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>        

        <div class="form-group">
            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DoctorSpecialityId, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })*@
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Doctor Speciality ID</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DoctorSpecialityId, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DoctorSpecialityId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Charges, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Charges, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Charges)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNo, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNo, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNo)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WardId, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.WardId, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WardId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap it in quotes to make it string:

```
var JsonModel = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';

alert(JsonModel); // json as string

var model = JSON.parse(JsonModel); // will give json
```